# Inno setup Query in Skip Pages functionality

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am creating a set up which involves in conditionally skipping pages based on a value I get in the 3rd page. I create all the possible pages in the `InitializeWizard()` and while debugging I can see all the pages created. When I try to skip pages in the `ShouldSkipPage`, I am unable to skip as I expected.

**At which scenario a page becomes invalid or is there any way to check through log or something about the status of the page.**

P.S - The page is very much valid and available and I am only not able to skip it.

The code snippet is given below...

```
[Code]

var
PageSQL2008SetupFile2: Integer;
PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2: Integer;
PageSQL2012SetupFile2: Integer;
PageSQL2014SetupFile2: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
        MyModeTypical := false;

                PageProductName := CreateInputQueryPage(wpSelectComponents,
                'Settings',
                'Product Name',
                'Please specify the product name, then click Next.');

                PageProductName.Add('Product Name:', False);
                PageProductName.Values[0] := ProductName;
//SQL Server selection page
                PageSQLServerSelection := CreateInputOptionPage(PageProductName.ID,
                'SQL Server Selection', 'Please select the version of SQL Server you want to install.',
                '',
                True, False);

                PageSQLServerSelection.Add('SQL 2008');
                PageSQLServerSelection.Add('SQL 2008R2');
                PageSQLServerSelection.Add('SQL 2012');
                PageSQLServerSelection.Add('SQL 2014');

                PageSQLServerSelection.Values[0] := False;
                PageSQLServerSelection.Values[1] := False;
                PageSQLServerSelection.Values[2] := False;
                PageSQLServerSelection.Values[3] := False;

// Creating Setup pages for the 4 servers
                PageSQL2008SetupFile2 := MSSQL2008SETUPDIR_CreatePage(PageSQLServerSelection.ID);

                PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2 := MSSQL2008R2SETUPDIR_CreatePage(PageSQL2008SetupFile2);

                PageSQL2012SetupFile2 := MSSQL2012SETUPDIR_CreatePage(PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2);

                PageSQL2014SetupFile2 := MSSQL2014SETUPDIR_CreatePage(PageSQL2012SetupFile2);

// some more logic...

end;

// Function for creating the Setup pages for 4 SQL Servers (Same logic for all 4 servers)

function MSSQL2008SETUPDIR_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  BMPFile: String;
begin
  SelectedSQLServerVersion := GetSQLServerVersion('');
  Page := CreateCustomPage(
    PreviousPageId,
    ExpandConstant('Database Settings'),
    ExpandConstant('Special note for the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup')
  );

        BMPFile:= ExpandConstant('{tmp}\caution.bmp');
        if not FileExists(BMPFile) then ExtractTemporaryFile(ExtractFileName(BMPFile));
{ BitmapImage1 }
  BitmapImage1 := TBitmapImage.Create(Page);
  with BitmapImage1 do
  begin
        Bitmap.LoadFromFile(BMPFile);
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(8);
    Top := ScaleY(8);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(209);
  end;
  { NewStaticText1 }
  NewStaticText1 := TNewStaticText.Create(Page);
  with NewStaticText1 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
        Caption := 'To install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 you have to insert the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup CD, when XXX setup requests it. The installation path of your Microsoft SQL Server 2008 setup and the additional Service Packs can be defined on the next pages.';
        Left := ScaleX(112);
    Top := ScaleY(8);
    Width := ScaleX(292);
    Height := ScaleY(77);
    AutoSize := False;
    TabOrder := 0;
    WordWrap := True;
  end;

  { NewStaticText2 }
  NewStaticText2 := TNewStaticText.Create(Page);
  with NewStaticText2 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption :=
      'CAUTION: When autorun is activated, dont click in the autorun menu of Microsoft SQL Server 2008.' + #13 +
      'Otherwise you must reboot your machine and restart the setup !';
    Left := ScaleX(112);
    Top := ScaleY(88);
    Width := ScaleX(293);
    Height := ScaleY(62);
    AutoSize := False;
    Font.Color := -16777208;
    Font.Height := ScaleY(-11);
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Font.Style := [fsBold];
    ParentFont := False;
    TabOrder := 1;
    WordWrap := True;
  end;

  with Page do
  begin
    //OnActivate := @MSSQLSETUPDIR_Activate;
    //OnShouldSkipPage := @MSSQLSETUPDIR_ShouldSkipPage;
        //OnBackButtonClick := @MSSQLSETUPDIR_BackButtonClick;
    //OnNextButtonClick := @MSSQLSETUPDIR_NextButtonClick;
    //OnCancelButtonClick := @MSSQLSETUPDIR_CancelButtonClick;
  end;

  Result := Page.ID;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;

var

begin
        if PageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
                Result := MyModeTypical;
        end else if PageID = PageProductName.ID then begin
                Result := MyModeTypical;
        end;
        Log('Server is...' + SelectedSQLServerVersion);
        if SelectedSQLServerVersion <> '' then begin
        // Database Settings Warning
                if (SQLServer2008Flag = True) and (IsComponentSelected('DBS\SERVER')) then begin
                        if PageID = PageSQL2008SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := false;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2012SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2014SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end;

                end else if (SQLServer2008R2Flag = True) and (IsComponentSelected('DBS\SERVER')) then begin
                        if PageID = PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := false;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2012SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2014SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2008SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end;

                end else if (SQLServer2012Flag = True) and (IsComponentSelected('DBS\SERVER')) then begin
                        if PageID = PageSQL2012SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := false;
                // This PageSQL2014SetupFile2 is not skipped.....
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2014SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                // This PageSQL2008SetupFile2 and PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2 are skipped properly.....
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2008SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end;

                end else if (SQLServer2014Flag = True) and (IsComponentSelected('DBS\SERVER')) then begin
                        if PageID = PageSQL2014SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := false;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2008SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2008R2SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end else if PageID = PageSQL2012SetupFile2 then begin
                                Result := true;
                        end;
                end;
// some more logic

end;
```

DeeJay

Comment: *I am unable to skip as I expected*, well, then it's time to ask, how do you skip the pages ? The scenario is quite simple, you create a page and hold a reference to it in a variable (each page must have its own). Then in the `ShouldSkipPage` event handler you test whether the `PageID` parameter value equals to your page `ID` (through that reference variable) and return `True` to the `Result` if you want to skip the page, `False` otherwise (for all the other pages you need to return `False`).

Comment: For instance, I ve created 4 setup pages for 4 different SQL Versions (2008, 2008R2, 2012 and 2014). Each page is linked to the previous page in the order I mentioned. If I select the SQL Server version as 2012, I am able to skip the 2008 and 2008R2 setup pages but not the 2014 setup page. Though I can see the PageID in debug mode it is not skipping the same.

Comment: @TLama, the code snippet is available http://pastebin.com/VDYESRYe

Comment: The code snippet needs to be *here*, in your question, where everyone can see it, and where it can be certain it will still exist in the future for the benefit of others.

Comment: @KenWhite, added the code snippet in the question.

Comment: I see a *link* to the code snippet in the question; I don't see the code. Please read my last comment again.